# Build with frontend-maven-plugin fails on mac M1: Could not download Node.js

Tags: maven, frontend-maven-plugin

The `frontend-maven-plugin` tries to download a node file which does not exist.

When I look into https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.3 I can only see a file named `node-v10.15.3-darwin-x64.tar.gz`

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ oauth-ui-authorization-code-angular-zuul ---
[INFO] Installing node version v10.15.3
[INFO] Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.3/node-v10.15.3-darwin-arm64.tar.gz to /Users/me/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/10.15.3/node-10.15.3-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mymodule 2.2.6.RELEASE FAILURE [  4.536 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  36.930 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-28T14:28:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project mymodule: Could not download Node.js: Got error code 404 from the server. -> [Help 1]
```

[ERROR]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the `frontend-maven-plugin`.
An upgrade to the current version should help:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
    ...
```

Thanks to:

- https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/10804
- https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/m1-mac-cant-build-wknd-tutorial-get-quot-could-not-download-node/m-p/399462